Use of property of integrals in the proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus
The proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus starts like this:
$$F'(x)= \lim_{h\to 0} = \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h} = $$
$$(1)\  \lim_{h\to 0}\ \frac{1}{h}\left[ \int_{a}^{x+h} f(t)dt) \ - \int_{a}^{x} f(t)dt \right]=$$
$$(2)\ \lim_{h\to 0}\ \frac{1}{h}\left[ \int_{a}^{x+h} f(t)dt) \ + \int_{x}^{a} f(t)dt \right]=$$
$$(3)\ \lim_{h\to 0}\ \frac{1}{h}\left[ \int_{x}^{x+h} f(t)dt)  \right]$$
I don't understand why in (2) you change the limits of integration of $$ - \int_{a}^{x} f(t)dt$$.
To me is more intuitive to see that $$\int_{x}^{x+h} f(t)dt$$ is the result of $$\int_{a}^{x+h} f(t)dt \ - \int_{a}^{x} f(t)dt$$ than the result of $$\int_{a}^{x+h} f(t)dt) \ + \int_{x}^{a} f(t)dt$$
In the last case $$\int_{x}^{a} f(t)dt$$ the integration is made from right to left, from $x$ to $a$, and the increments of x, $\Delta x$, of its Riemann sum are negative. So that the integral is negative is f(t) is positive.
For instance if you have $$\int_{3}^{6} f(t)dt \ - \int_{9}^{6} f(t)dt$$ then is more intuitive to write it as $$\int_{3}^{6} f(t)dt \ + \int_{6}^{9} f(t)dt \ = \ \int_{3}^{9} f(t)d $$
But this is not the case in the change of the limits of integration in (2).
My question is: what's the use of step (2)? Why do you need to do it? What does it clarify?
source: https://openstax.org/books/calculus-volume-1/pages/5-3-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus

I'm very used to the identity, abbreviated somewhat, $$\int_a^b + \int_b^c = \int_a^c\text{.}$$  Of course, it's an easy lemma that $$\int_b^c = \int_a^c - \int_a^b\text{,}$$ but if that's not on the "official list of integral manipulation identities" in your toolbox, you don't get to use that lemma.  And it's worth noting that $a$, $b$, and $c$ can be in any order on the real line (as long as the integrand is integrable on the resulting intervals).

My doubt is why do you need step (2)?

As @Eric commented, you need it or not, depending on your "toolbox".

I assume that all you need to understand fully is the tiny and easy lemma given by Eric Towers. Just to add that our teacher did not present so detailed 1-2-3 steps, but only the final $(3)\ \lim_{h\to 0}\ \frac{1}{h}\left[ \int_{x}^{x+h} f(t)dt)  \right]$ which sometimes is also more straight-forward provided $f(t)$ is the derivative of $F(x)$ and integrable with the given limits.

@MathArt Not "provided $f(t)$
is the derivative of $F(x)$"! $F'=f$ is precisely the content of the FTC which is to be proved.

@Anne Bauval, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Relationship_between_the_parts is saying that it almost looks like the first part of the theorem follows directly from the second. I guess it is where my teacher made use confused.
